# unable to connect to nginx hosted website from most pcs, yet my local pc connects fine?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, connection, website

i run a website (remotely) using nginx and php, which has been ok for a long while. i recently changed the domain name to a new name and now most web browsers/pcs are unable to connect to the website. they see 'unable to connect' type messages in the browser (e.g. firefox).

the strange aspect is that i am able to connect just fine from my home pc, to the website via the standard internet. yet when i use another pc on the same home network, the connection fails (equally so for other pcs on other IP addresses).

there are no firewall issues as far as i am aware. pings report responses and traceroutes looks ok to me.

so this appears to be a configuration issue on the server.

i have created a new ssl certificate for the new domain (via startssl), which appears to be working ok. the domain name is routed to the server in the same way as the previous domain name was being routed.

so i am stuck..

anyone care to assist and test here? the domain name is www.ureka.org.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.ureka.org doesn't have an address record in the DNS, so *nobody* can find it.

To resolve the problem, add the appropriate AAAA and A records for your IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

Comment: hmm... no, there is no entry in the local hosts file for ureka.org to point to the server.
i am looking here at the DNS record for the domain and there are A records listed for ureka.org and *.ureka.org - which point to the correct server and which are the same format as my other domains which are ok.

what is the origin of your observance that the DNS record does not exist? maybe the domain registrar has broken something.
thanks

Comment: I tried looking it up. You have _only_ a TXT record for google-site-verification, for www.ureka.org. You _do_ have a proper A record for ureka.org.

Comment: ok thanks. i needed to add an A record specifically for www.ureka.org. the record with the wildcard subdomain was being ignored - i do not know why.

Comment: Because it already has a TXT record!

Comment: ah, so the google verification record is intended to be listed for domain.tld and not for www.domain.tld.
i made the changes and all is well. thanks so much. :)